# Why is jQuery .ajax wrapping get data in quotes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm stumped on a particular .ajax request that is wrapping data in double-quotes before appending the data to the request URL.

```
function callAPI(endpoint, request_type, request_data, callback) {

    var request_payload, request_content;

    if (request_type === "get") {
        request_payload = request_data;
        request_content = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    } else {
        request_payload = JSON.stringify(request_data);
        request_content = "application/json";
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: request_type,
        url: api_url + endpoint,
        contentType: request_content,
        data: request_payload, // access in body
    }).done(function(data, statusText, xhr) {
        callback(xhr.status, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(), data);
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
        callback(xhr.status);
    }).always(function() {
        console.log("finished call API " + endpoint);
    });

}
```

The output renders in the browser address bar as: [https://myurl.com/api/v1/device?%22sort[name]=name&sort[direction]=asc%22](https://myurl.com/api/v1/device?%22sort%5Bname%5D=name&sort%5Bdirection%5D=asc%22)

I wasn't using the if conditions until I started trying to get rid of the quotes. When I print request_data to console, no quotes. The data going into request_data looks like this:

```
var request_body = "sort[name]=" + sorts + "&sort[direction]=" + direction;
```

I've tried several different variations of this including wrapping in {} but no luck. Anyone have any ideas? I'm sure it's so simple I'm just tired of looking at the same lines of code :)

Comment: are you stringifying a string? `console.log(JSON.stringify("a"))`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into a similar issue, I solved my own problem. Turns out my request data was being handled by a function that used JSON.stringify against it before it got to the ajax call.